# Изменение формата даты и времени в таблице mysql

Tags: mysql

В столбце "title" таблицы wp_foro_posts дата и время отображаются так: 
2009.08.12 22:56:04, нужно sql запросом сделать так: 
2009-08-12 22:56:04, то есть вместо точек применить тире. 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, пример sql запроса к таблице.

Спасибо.

Comment: Где отображаются?

Comment: в ячейке строки, столбца title, это дата создания поста темы.

Comment: В mysql формат  'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' по умолчанию для полей типа datetime. Если у вас по другому отображается в каком-то конкретном приложении, то укажите в каком

Comment: Спасибо, я стал понимать немного. Если я установлю столбцу тип "datetime" станет ли он корректно отображаться, автоматически? То есть так 2009-08-12 22:56:04 сейчас это столбец имеет тип varchar(255). WORDPRESS плагин форума не понимает такую дату 2009.08.12 22:56:04.

Comment: У MySQL есть только один формат **хранения** даты-времени. YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss. И желать его изменить - это хотеть написать свой MySQL, с блэк... ну ты понял. А вот **отображением** хранимых значений MySQL не занимается. Совсем. Этим занимаются клиентские приложения. Их и надо "строить".

Answer (score 0):

Лучше всего на стороне PHP сделать **str_replace('-','.',$date)** далее уже запрос.

Если чисто на SQL, то будет очень длинный код с SUBSTRING, LEN и кучей '+'-ов.

Comment: К сожалению, мне не под силам это. Постое изменение типа поля на datetime не приведет к изменению отображения?

Comment: Да, проверили только что. При изменении на dataime значение 2009.08.12 22:56:04 превратиться в 2009-08-12 22:56:04. Обнуления не будет. Можете пробовать, однако, на всякий случай сделайте резервную копию базы.

Comment: Благодарю. вас.